# Issue in combining the Unity project with an existing Xcode swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have successfully integrated `unity` generated `Xcode` project in my existing `Xcode` project.

My existing `Xcode` project has lot of `pods` installed and I also have custom `config` file `“debug.xcconfig”` set in `"Project->Info-Configuratios->Debug settings"`.

When I install pods with `pod install` command it come up with this warning.

> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `ProjectName` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`../debug.xcconfig`).

Although `pods` get installed successfully.

As the above warning suggest I included `“Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName.debug.xcconfig”` to top of  my custom `config` file i.e `“debug.xcconfig”`.

Project is get compiled successfully. Now issues is arise when I used any of installed `pods` in my existing project with below errors.

> “Cannot find protocol declaration for 'GIDSignInDelegate’”
>
> “Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ARSessionDelegate’” etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved the issues just by importing above mentioned Pods in my objectiveC bridging header file.

'Just like #import'

> ## import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
>
> ## import <ARkit/ARkit.h>